# PHP call class method in another file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two files, one file has a class and a method to connect to the database, the second file has a class to login a user and of course I need to call the class and method in the second file to allow the login.

The problem I am having is when i Call the file that contains the class and method to connect is undefined.

File 1 "Connection Details"

```
    <?php

class dbConnect{

    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $user = 'root';
    protected $pass = 'root';
    protected $db = 'bolt_mail';

    public function connect(){
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->db) or die('Cannot Connect to DB');
        return $con;
    }

}
```

File 2 "Login"

```
class login{

public function con(){
    include ('connect.php');

    $db = new dbConnect();
    $db->connect();

     return $db;
}

public function getLogin($email, $pass){



    $sql = "SELECT ott_email, ott_password ,app_password , user_status, account_type FROM tbl_user WHERE ott_email='$email' AND app_password='$pass'";
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Errors:

```
    Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_ott/php/login.php on line 38

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_ott/php/login.php on line 39
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong...?

Comment: You have to return the return value of `$db->connect();`, instead of `$db`

Comment: @sanketh  where did you see attribute $con ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public function con(){
    include ('connect.php');

    $db = new dbConnect();
   $conn =  $db->connect();

     return $conn ;
}
```

You are trying to return the object of class dbConnect and not the return of function connect. Also your db connection design needs to be improved, have a look at singleton pattern

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the first warning, `mysqli_query()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, not some other object(in your case it's your `dbConnect` object that is returned by `con`). Since you are returning the mysqli connection from your `connect` method, you should return that same connection in your `con` function to be used by `mysqli_query()`. Try this...

```
class login{

public function con(){
    include ('connect.php');

    $db = new dbConnect();
    return $db->connect();
}
```

Comment: aaaa this is perfect...! i though if i just return the $db variable i will be ok did not though of doing it this way.... could you explain to me why it did not work the way I did it...?

Answer (score 0):

Move this string

```
include ('connect.php');
```

to the top of Your second file, in other words, outside the class login.
And this strings:

```
$db->connect();

return $db;
```

change to:

```
return $db->connect();
```